# Is min_tag_id in tag_recent_media sequential or ordered?

Tags: instagram

If I call instagram api(**tag_recent_media**) with **min_tag_id** and fetch say 20 images each time then the min_tag_id does not increment sequentially. Everywhere it is said that is a cursor to your previous search, if so, it must increment by 20 each time ... its not happening ... Does it follow any order?

How many images does pagination.next_url return?

Please tell a way to keep my database up to date ...

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a little late for you but I figured I'd try and offer an answer since no one else has. I've been working with the Insagram gem in rails and if you're paginating and want to get the next set of images, you need to change max_tag_id to the next_max_tag_id. It'll fetch the next set of images, the default is 20, but there is a count option you can throw that can go up to 33.

Correct me if I'm wrong. Still working with the gem and it's pretty wonky, but this is what I've gathered from my experience.